# How to optimize this slow SQL query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a slow SQL query on my Drupal website and I don't know how to optimize it.

Here is the query that Views produces: http://pastebin.com/StAEiXbY

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20081/1/0

EXPLAIN shows this: http://pastebin.com/uKtte5KR

Amount of data (rows):

```
+-------+----------------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+
| node  | content_type_profile | userpoints | node_revisions | node_access | term_node |
+-------+----------------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+
| 59805 |                23294 |       2692 |          71284 |      147783 |    225052 |
+-------+----------------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------+
```

This query takes more than 10s to complete. How can I optimize this query?

Comment: Put an explain before that query and edit your question with the resulting table.

Comment: Can you show us the indexes on the `node` table?

Comment: Try a composite index on `node_access(nid,grant_view,gid,realm)`

Comment: Also one on `node_users(uid,type)`

Comment: @Mihai The query execution time remains the same with those indexes. But in the mean time I found  a solution. See below and don't hesitate to comment. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactoring the query like this gives better performance (from ~7s to ~0.364s on my local):
http://pastebin.com/7VpLGdQB

EXPLAIN now shows this: http://pastebin.com/q8zEkXbx

Joining the node table twice was the bottleneck. The subquery with node and content_type_profile tables is much more efficient.

On the Drupal side I'll find a way to change this using hook_query_alter or by creating a custom block.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the query via e.g. phpMyAdmin and append the keyword explain. This should give you insights in how the query uses available indexes and where an extra index should help.

That said, Drupal's database structure is already pretty decent configured with indexes and such. Do you really need the view to execute that query on every page load? If not, you can enable query and/or output caching on a view. Simply edit the view, click open the advanced section if it's not already open en click the text next to caching to configure the caching behaviour.

Comment: I edited my question the EXPLAIN is above. Still... lots of users are editing nodes which results in a cache clear quite often. This view is not shown on all pages but still quite a lot. I'm not an SQL expert but to me it looks like the DB structure that Content Profile uses is the problem. Maybe this query can't be optimized. Thanks